# using form in web2py SQLFORM.factory and adding 2 require for same field

Tags: python, database, web2py, web2py-modules

i am trying to use SQLFORM.factory in web2py and in one of the tables i have field where i want to use requires 2 times but it gives an error i know there is some way how you are supposed to do it but i dont know how. 
i am new to web2py

```
form = SQLFORM.factory(
    Field('email', requires=IS_NOT_EMPTY(), requires = IS_EMAIL(error_message='invalid email'))
    )
```

here i want to put both conditions that field email is of type email and should not be empty which are 2 different require fields but how to join them or somthing???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm new to web2py as well but I believe you need to put them in a python list.  Like this:

```
form = SQLFORM.factory(
    Field('email', requires=[IS_NOT_EMPTY(), IS_EMAIL(error_message='invalid email')])
    )
```

See the documentation where they talk about Multiple validators: http://www.web2py.com/book/default/chapter/07#Validators